# How use ViewPager2 to display CardView with another ViewPager2 within it as an image slider

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is to have one ViewPager2 which will show a custom item,
that is a CardView which will contain another ViewPager2 which will act as an image slider.

This is my CardView which implements the second ViewPager2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/imageSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewProductName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="@string/product_name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My question is how to create a ViewPager2 adapter that uses this CardView as an item and populate the image slider? For loading the images i am using Glide.

Comment: Instead, Why not go with a `ViewPager2` with a Horizontal Scrolling `RecyclerView` for Scrollable Carousel View? Way easy to handle and configure. Just pass the list of images to the RecyclerView's adapter and it will populate them, you can use RecyclreView's decoration for dots indicator.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Thanks for the suggestion. I looked into it as you said. And managed to solve the problem. :)

Comment: That's good if you've solved it. If you get stuck somewhere, feel free to ask.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Will do. I am still trying to figure out how I can actually nest ViewPager2 for future reference as in my question.